# API Authorization flow

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, authorization

I'm having a difficult time trying to set up my authorization flow for an API. I feel like I have everything but still getting a "Key Error". Any help would be much appreciated!

```
# Auth URL
auth_endpoint = 'https://api.website.data.com/auth'

# Auth Headers
content_type = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
access_token = 'x-api-key: abc123'
accept = 'accept: application/json'
header_auth = {'content-type':content_type,
                'Authorization':authorization}


# Auth Body Params
username = 'apiuser.user@gmail.com'
password = 'password@123'
body_params = 'username={}&password={}'.format(username,password)


resp_auth = requests.request('POST',auth_endpoint,headers=header_auth,data=body_params)
acc_token = resp_auth.json()['access_token']
```

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Also, what API are you trying to connect to? Each API can have different specifications on how to authenticate. Without knowing what is the proper way to authenticate, it's hard to guess what is wrong with what you are doing

Comment: Check out the [requests auth documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/)

Comment: @FlorentMonin I'm getting "Key Error: 'access_token'" This is for the Music Connect API by Luminate.

Comment: Looks like the response from the API doesn't contain the `access_token` key, so when you try to access it, you get an error. You should do some basic error catching on the response like `if not resp_auth.ok: print(f"Got an error from the API: {resp_auth.body}"`, to get more information on what is going wrong